# CM3 GPT Partition Table and U-Boot

Tags: partition, compute-module-3, compute-module, u-boot, yocto

I am working in yocto currently to develop an image for my compute module boards (both CM3 and CM4) , It was my understanding that using yocto I should be easily able to switch between the hardwares depending on which one I was building for at the time. This seemed to be perfect for me up until a few days ago when I had been working on the partition table with my CM4 and added U-Boot. This worked fine for the CM4 and the build works perfectly, I have 5 partitions with GPT and I can see the boot loader is U-Boot when I stop it.

Changing the device back to the CM3 though causes the module to not boot up. Ive gone back and iterated through my changes and discovered that doing either of the actions below will cause this behavior on the cm3 but not the cm4:

1- Enable U-boot. This one is very surprising considering it is documented the meta-raspberry layer found here: https://meta-raspberrypi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra-build-config.html#boot-to-u-boot

The change should just be as simple as adding the line below to your local.conf so I'm very surprised doing this seems to cause so many problems

```
#Enable u-boot
RPI_USE_U_BOOT = "1"
```

2- Changing the partition table to  GPT instead of MSDOS. This one is less surprising. Looking online there seems to be some mention of the CM3 not supporting GPT but I couldn't find anything mentioning that in official documentation so if someone could confirm or deny this for me it would be great. But also a shame the module doesn't support a more modern partitioning scheme.

If that's not the cause and its just a mistake on my part Ill post that section of my image creation .bbclass below so you all can tell me what im doing wrong

Working Code:

```
    # Create partition table
    parted -s ${SDIMG} mklabel msdos
    # Create boot partition and mark it as bootable
    parted -s ${SDIMG} unit KiB mkpart primary fat32 ${IMAGE_ROOTFS_ALIGNMENT} $(expr ${ALIGNED_BOOT_SIZE} + ${IMAGE_ROOTFS_ALIGNMENT})
    parted -s ${SDIMG} set 1 boot on
    # Create rootfs partition to hold the squashfs
    parted -s ${SDIMG} unit KiB mkpart primary ext4 $(expr ${ALIGNED_BOOT_SIZE} + ${IMAGE_ROOTFS_ALIGNMENT}) $(expr ${ALIGNED_BOOT_SIZE} + ${IMAGE_ROOTFS_ALIGNMENT} + ${ALIGNED_SQUASHFS_SIZE})
    # Create overlay partition
    parted -s ${SDIMG} -- unit KiB mkpart primary ext4 ${IMAGE_OVERLAY_START} -1s
    parted ${SDIMG} print
```

Broken Code :

```
    # Create partition table
    parted -s ${SDIMG} mklabel gpt
    # Create boot partition and mark it as bootable
    parted -s ${SDIMG} unit KiB mkpart primary fat32 ${IMAGE_ROOTFS_ALIGNMENT} $(expr ${ALIGNED_BOOT_SIZE} + ${IMAGE_ROOTFS_ALIGNMENT})
    parted -s ${SDIMG} set 1 boot on
    # Create rootfs partition to hold the squashfs
    parted -s ${SDIMG} unit KiB mkpart primary ext4 $(expr ${ALIGNED_BOOT_SIZE} + ${IMAGE_ROOTFS_ALIGNMENT}) $(expr ${ALIGNED_BOOT_SIZE} + ${IMAGE_ROOTFS_ALIGNMENT} + ${ALIGNED_SQUASHFS_SIZE})
    # Create overlay partition
    parted -s ${SDIMG} -- unit KiB mkpart primary ext4 ${IMAGE_OVERLAY_START} -1s
    parted ${SDIMG} print
```

Im feeling very stuck on this so any help people can offer would be greatly appreciated  :D